# What does Fujitsu call an "RFID LSI"?

Tags: rfid, non-volatile-memory

Fujitsu offers ferroelectric RAM modules, [including in "RFID LSI" format](http://www.fujitsu.com/global/products/devices/semiconductor/memory/fram/lineup/index.html). I have no idea what those are, and the engrish documentation doesn't help at all.

Comment: The datasheet makes it reasonably clear. It's a FRAM chip with a RFID interface.

Comment: I'm wondering what the acronym refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) = Radio Frequency IDentification

[LSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit#Generations) = Large-Scale Integration (chip)

In this context LSI probably just means that it's at least a moderately complex chip, rather than being a precise category of complexity. This is fairly typical Japanese-English terminology.